# ¿Existen las palabras «nosotras» y «vosotras»?

Tags: pronombres

¿Es posible usar **nosotras** o **vosotras**? Nunca las he oido, pero pienso que tal vez son como *ellas*, pero para la primera y segunda personas del plural, respectivamente. ¿Han oido ustedes estas palabras?

Comment: *Yo* no puedo usar "nosotras", pero...

Comment: *Nosotras* también se puede referir a [este producto](http://aplicaciones.familiasancela.com/servlet/co.com.pragma.familia.catProductos.servlet.Base?PJR_TEMPLATE_NAME=secundaria2&intMarca=1&intCategoria=1&x=).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sí, se pueden usar. Yo soy una mujer, y cuando estoy con mis *amigas*, se puede decir:

> Nosotras vamos al cine.

También se puede referir a nuestro grupo en la misma forma.

> Alguien me ha dicho que vosotras vais al cine.

Comment: ¡Eek! Mea culpa; he estudiado español más mexicana o de américa central. No estoy acostumbrada de usar la persona segunda plural. También estas teclas son la más peores para escribir español. Gracias por su ayuda. :)

Comment: You also have some problems with masculine and feminine form for words... but don't worry, you'll learn here :)

Comment: Eek. I am clearly just so bad at this whole spelling thing. I know why I messed it up; the usual conjugation requires an accent (*andar* => *andáis*) but *ir* does not.

Comment: Vais has no accent.

Comment: *"Yo he escuchado"*? I would say *"He oído"*, sound more natural to me, but I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 4):

Si, ambas existen y son usadas.

**Vosotras** es usada en España; en otras regiones se usa **ustedes** tanto para mujeres como para hombres.

Con **nosotras** hay un tema particular: normalmente al haber un grupo de mujeres, y hablar ellas mismas del grupo, usan **nosotras**, pero si hay al menos 1 hombre en el grupo ya se usa **nosotros**.

Comment: Note the implicit statement: *vosotras* is not used at all in Latin America - *ustedes* is instead.

Answer (score 4):

Sí, de hecho en [la comparación en Google NgramViewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nosotras,vosotras&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=10&smoothing=3) se puede ver que ambas se han usado, pero `vosotras` va hacia la baja.

Agrego la imagen de la comparación acá mismo:

[image: Comparación nosotras/vosotras en Google nGram Viewer]

Comment: Más que probablemente la explosión del "nosotras" tenga mucho que ver con el ascenso de la corrección política, precisamente en los últimos veinte años.

Comment: Yes both terms are clearly on the rise since the 1980s but *vosotras* is much less common than *nosotras* probably because only one country in the Spanish speaking world uses the second person plural.

Answer (score 4):

Nosotras es la forma femenina de Nosotros (both mean "We" in English), por lo que un grupo de mujeres se referirían a ellas mismas como Nosotras.

Lo mismo aplica a Vosotras (usado generalmente solo en España) pero significa "(plural) you" (instead of "We") refiriendose a un grupo de mujeres por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they exist, and they are used exactly like *ellas*: when speaking about an entirely female group.